# Error when connecting Google search Console to BigQuery with appscript

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-search-console

I have been following this tutorial https://adaptpartners.com/technical-seo/a-tool-for-saving-google-search-console-data-to-bigquery/#comment-683  to integrate google search console with bigquery.

I have tried to follow the tutorial exactly but when I run a cron job the bigquery table doesnt populate for some reason!!

Here is the error log. Any help on this very welcome. Thank you.

```
2018-10-15 17:24:08.736 BST
GET
200
137 B
4.7 s
AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
/cron/

0.1.0.1 – – [15/Oct/2018:17:24:08 +0100] “GET /cron/ HTTP/1.1” 200 137 – “AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)” “arc-02.appspot.com” ms=4732 cpu_ms=882 cpm_usd=1.531e-8 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117c1379831333cb1e0bdef997282d17c1beef60cee10afc4ad0b6bc0e559f9c203d4f app_engine_release=1.9.65 trace_id=81b013f4a26a94b340c562817d0aae11

{
httpRequest: {
status: 200
}
insertId: “5bc4bf2d00082281d37205a4”
labels: {
clone_id: “00c61b117c1379831333cb1e0bdef997282d17c1beef60cee10afc4ad0b6bc0e559f9c203d4f”
}
logName: “projects/arc-02/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log”
operation: {
first: true
id: “5bc4bf2800ff0b3e3c1000ff460b0001657e6172632d30320001323031383130313574313032353535000100”
last: true
producer: “appengine.googleapis.com/request_id”
}
protoPayload: {
@type: “type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog”
appEngineRelease: “1.9.65”
appId: “e~arc-02”
cost: 1.531e-8
endTime: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.469487Z”
finished: true
first: true
host: “arc-02.appspot.com”
httpVersion: “HTTP/1.1”
instanceId: “00c61b117c1379831333cb1e0bdef997282d17c1beef60cee10afc4ad0b6bc0e559f9c203d4f”
ip: “0.1.0.1”
latency: “4.732659s”
line: [
0: {
logMessage: “URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/webmasters/v3/rest?userIp=0.1.0.1”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.379498Z”
}
1: {
logMessage: “Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.379919Z”
}
2: {
logMessage: “[‘eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ijc5YTQyZjlhOGQ3ZGNkYWI1NTIzNzZkODg3NDg4YzljOTUzOTNkMTgifQ’, ‘eyJpc3MiOiJnc2MtbG9nZ2VyQGFyYy0wMi5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9iaWdxdWVyeSBodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9hdXRoL3dlYm1hc3RlcnMucmVhZG9ubHkiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTUzOTYyNDI1MSwiaWF0IjoxNTM5NjIwNjUxfQ’, ‘LXe2MKG1jtvcDo7_18PSiAEMT82EbhoNX21bvs26QJCQ4Dr_KEPHGPqUB6TmV5-K6GK1RPB1h6f6aqcR3kP_OF2rIx9TMpMQUliIfoctjnfx-VvDVT4Elyx2lm8b2REUkbhXI3_dYHtF4gKW7rIm7q0OZ1DHNGgH_1g1mpH9nuX-TxTb0C5ibc_OvfXii3RdeVGlL9EbGEzsq1PZnHn3nZeNsr-3upAWaAWltpm5bFv7QshEIj6Tc9DwDQxxZ3LYFzc_JrDlWi56YR19P9UMlIJyRZigCejJkXgqafxV7T4nkUUXw9sXY-eeKgA18yhXj0MU3X84vwsE5TOm9LqJ9Q’]”
severity: “DEBUG”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.386625Z”
}
3: {
logMessage: “Refreshing access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.386896Z”
}
4: {
logMessage: “URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites?alt=json”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.503233Z”
}
5: {
logMessage: “{u’siteEntry’: [{u’permissionLevel’: u’siteFullUser’, u’siteUrl’: u’http://www.freshegg.co.uk/’}]}”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.553087Z”
}
6: {
logMessage: “URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest?userIp=0.1.0.1”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.557639Z”
}
7: {
logMessage: “Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.557857Z”
}
8: {
logMessage: “[‘eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ijc5YTQyZjlhOGQ3ZGNkYWI1NTIzNzZkODg3NDg4YzljOTUzOTNkMTgifQ’, ‘eyJpc3MiOiJnc2MtbG9nZ2VyQGFyYy0wMi5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9iaWdxdWVyeSBodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9hdXRoL3dlYm1hc3RlcnMucmVhZG9ubHkiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTUzOTYyNDI1MSwiaWF0IjoxNTM5NjIwNjUxfQ’, ‘LXe2MKG1jtvcDo7_18PSiAEMT82EbhoNX21bvs26QJCQ4Dr_KEPHGPqUB6TmV5-K6GK1RPB1h6f6aqcR3kP_OF2rIx9TMpMQUliIfoctjnfx-VvDVT4Elyx2lm8b2REUkbhXI3_dYHtF4gKW7rIm7q0OZ1DHNGgH_1g1mpH9nuX-TxTb0C5ibc_OvfXii3RdeVGlL9EbGEzsq1PZnHn3nZeNsr-3upAWaAWltpm5bFv7QshEIj6Tc9DwDQxxZ3LYFzc_JrDlWi56YR19P9UMlIJyRZigCejJkXgqafxV7T4nkUUXw9sXY-eeKgA18yhXj0MU3X84vwsE5TOm9LqJ9Q’]”
severity: “DEBUG”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.561732Z”
}
9: {
logMessage: “Refreshing access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.561930Z”
}
10: {
logMessage: “URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/arc-02/datasets/gsc_logger_sites?alt=json”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:11.789496Z”
}
11: {
logMessage: “URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/arc-02/datasets/gsc_logger_sites?alt=json”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.099439Z”
}
12: {
logMessage: “Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.099658Z”
}
13: {
logMessage: “[‘eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ijc5YTQyZjlhOGQ3ZGNkYWI1NTIzNzZkODg3NDg4YzljOTUzOTNkMTgifQ’, ‘eyJpc3MiOiJnc2MtbG9nZ2VyQGFyYy0wMi5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9iaWdxdWVyeSBodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9hdXRoL3dlYm1hc3RlcnMucmVhZG9ubHkiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTUzOTYyNDI1MiwiaWF0IjoxNTM5NjIwNjUyfQ’, ‘gLPFHNFevXceeZpb2uj6fNMyp_CkaBcX7591bs2DFTXBgAmGpNLvZPeFE0hXuvy4OAGoYcA2OMrvQ8ej-xJvoDyerBXbAKKGKPgG2misHKaeQpFS1q2l2ogRVHkwYq3q5BO9ga-TVTv57l8bb_qe1VoqdRVicw4k5Wd1LeyhYVP0htfJ45Eh73kwMX0nS0LjWMaPMSiveFi4nGJNSknCNAZTyN98TnUcceE-8TDZ2IJhDaFFHaoaYBe11NEMZqB8nS__qALqOG-L5TBQyuMfuQyqTNp8WCLEkV1H2F6ahd8yiBPm4BkmsujuCshGpp1Y-SG1P7fSdsVN_awTcMZmvw’]”
severity: “DEBUG”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.103727Z”
}
14: {
logMessage: “Refreshing access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.103966Z”
}
15: {
logMessage: “URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/arc-02/datasets/gsc_logger_sites/tables?alt=json”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.399521Z”
}
16: {
logMessage: “Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.399797Z”
}
17: {
logMessage: “[‘eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ijc5YTQyZjlhOGQ3ZGNkYWI1NTIzNzZkODg3NDg4YzljOTUzOTNkMTgifQ’, ‘eyJpc3MiOiJnc2MtbG9nZ2VyQGFyYy0wMi5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9iaWdxdWVyeSBodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9hdXRoL3dlYm1hc3RlcnMucmVhZG9ubHkiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTUzOTYyNDI1MiwiaWF0IjoxNTM5NjIwNjUyfQ’, ‘gLPFHNFevXceeZpb2uj6fNMyp_CkaBcX7591bs2DFTXBgAmGpNLvZPeFE0hXuvy4OAGoYcA2OMrvQ8ej-xJvoDyerBXbAKKGKPgG2misHKaeQpFS1q2l2ogRVHkwYq3q5BO9ga-TVTv57l8bb_qe1VoqdRVicw4k5Wd1LeyhYVP0htfJ45Eh73kwMX0nS0LjWMaPMSiveFi4nGJNSknCNAZTyN98TnUcceE-8TDZ2IJhDaFFHaoaYBe11NEMZqB8nS__qALqOG-L5TBQyuMfuQyqTNp8WCLEkV1H2F6ahd8yiBPm4BkmsujuCshGpp1Y-SG1P7fSdsVN_awTcMZmvw’]”
severity: “DEBUG”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.404879Z”
}
18: {
logMessage: “Refreshing access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.410948Z”
}
19: {
logMessage: “Added 0 tables and deleted 0 tables.”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.698406Z”
}
20: {
logMessage: “Tables Audited”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:12.698617Z”
}
21: {
logMessage: “URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.freshegg.co.uk%2F/searchAnalytics/query?alt=json”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.284122Z”
}
22: {
logMessage: “Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.284339Z”
}
23: {
logMessage: “[‘eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ijc5YTQyZjlhOGQ3ZGNkYWI1NTIzNzZkODg3NDg4YzljOTUzOTNkMTgifQ’, ‘eyJpc3MiOiJnc2MtbG9nZ2VyQGFyYy0wMi5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9iaWdxdWVyeSBodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9hdXRoL3dlYm1hc3RlcnMucmVhZG9ubHkiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTUzOTYyNDI1MywiaWF0IjoxNTM5NjIwNjUzfQ’, ‘SbQKjxwBqDEZAp6pzbhlp87p-uvFlHAi0_MAugLH7eXA3OWyREyiWof6Gl6yg1PwQzewUF5QQ7NGhy5QPXEMFbQ8ypPKJiH-LEV3Bck-4TTaCOHcql93KhfC6vQ3erfhYKEYvbhG19tQsQcU2TZs-CehM-t4vK_Y1WuudpB2BDk_xiRDaoYabMUjb5QHVwE3EkGSsNhysRul-8a8DPJuW71tnweA0OvOPYAAx-z7aHBELAEwB3zFaVFBNjarq5vBwKv0oJdK8MUOjXg4H4HpMFXc4_K_ZQhBqGxrzDmhvqyOZzBNGjXMZdgxkvrWSJMz7d5tD1k-wAtJHOO7AoT2tQ’]”
severity: “DEBUG”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.288947Z”
}
24: {
logMessage: “Refreshing access_token”
severity: “INFO”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.289220Z”
}
25: {
logMessage: “{
“error”: {
“errors”: [
{
“domain”: “global”,
“reason”: “required”,
“message”: “dimensionFilterGroups[0].filters[0]: ‘dimension’ field is required.”,
“locationType”: “parameter”,
“location”: “dimension_filter_groups.filters.dimension”
},
{
“domain”: “global”,
“reason”: “required”,
“message”: “dimensionFilterGroups[0].filters[0]: ‘expression’ field is required.”,
“locationType”: “parameter”,
“location”: “dimension_filter_groups.filters.expression”
}
],
“code”: 400,
“message”: “dimensionFilterGroups[0].filters[0]: ‘dimension’ field is required.”
}
}
”
severity: “ERROR”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.466944Z”
}
26: {
logMessage: “Could not load data for http://www.freshegg.co.uk/”
severity: “ERROR”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.467221Z”
}
]
megaCycles: “882”
method: “GET”
pendingTime: “2.624428510s”
requestId: “5bc4bf2800ff0b3e3c1000ff460b0001657e6172632d30320001323031383130313574313032353535000100”
resource: “/cron/”
responseSize: “137”
startTime: “2018-10-15T16:24:08.736828Z”
status: 200
taskName: “b2c5ace5ef0cba4f839b24b3094597cc”
taskQueueName: “__cron”
traceId: “81b013f4a26a94b340c562817d0aae11”
traceSampled: true
urlMapEntry: “controllers.main.app”
userAgent: “AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)”
versionId: “20181015t102555”
}
receiveTimestamp: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.539576404Z”
resource: {
labels: {
module_id: “default”
project_id: “arc-02”
version_id: “20181015t102555”
zone: “eu2”
}
type: “gae_app”
}
severity: “ERROR”
timestamp: “2018-10-15T16:24:08.736828Z”
trace: “projects/arc-02/traces/81b013f4a26a94b340c562817d0aae11”
traceSampled: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read through this log? The errors are listed very plainly.

```
“error”: {
“errors”: [
{
“domain”: “global”,
“reason”: “required”,
“message”: “dimensionFilterGroups[0].filters[0]: ‘dimension’ field is required.”,
“locationType”: “parameter”,
“location”: “dimension_filter_groups.filters.dimension”
},
{
“domain”: “global”,
“reason”: “required”,
“message”: “dimensionFilterGroups[0].filters[0]: ‘expression’ field is required.”,
“locationType”: “parameter”,
“location”: “dimension_filter_groups.filters.expression”
}
],
“code”: 400,
“message”: “dimensionFilterGroups[0].filters[0]: ‘dimension’ field is required.”
}
}
”
severity: “ERROR”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.466944Z”
}
26: {
logMessage: “Could not load data for http://www.freshegg.co.uk/”
severity: “ERROR”
time: “2018-10-15T16:24:13.467221Z”
}
]
```